# Does $\lim_{x\to0}\left(\frac{\sin(x)}{x}\right)^{\frac{1}{x^2}} =0$?

Tags: calculus, limits

$$\lim_{x\to0}\left(\frac{\sin(x)}{x}\right)^{\frac{1}{x^2}} \stackrel{?}{=} 0$$

My calculations (usage of [L'Hôpital's rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule) will be denoted by `L` under the equal sign `=`):
(Sorry for the small font, but you can zoom in to see better with Firefox)
$$
\begin{align}
& \lim_{x\to0}\left(\frac{\sin(x)}{x}\right)^{\frac{1}{x^2}} = \\
& \lim_{x\to0}e^{\ln\left(\left(\frac{\sin(x)}{x}\right)^{\frac{1}{x^2}}\right)} = \\
& e^{\lim_{x\to0}\frac{1}{x^2}\ln\left(\left(\frac{\sin(x)}{x}\right)\right)} = \\
& e^{\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\ln\left(\left(\frac{\sin(x)}{x}\right)\right)}{x^2}} \stackrel{\frac{0}{0}}{\stackrel{=}{L}} \\
& e^{\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x}{2x \sin(x)}\cdot\frac{\cos(x)x -1\cdot\sin(x)}{x^2}} = \\
& e^{\lim_{x\to0}\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{\sin(x)}\cdot\left(\frac{\cos(x)}{x} - \frac{\sin(x)}{x^2}\right)} = \\
& e^{\lim_{x\to0}\frac{1}{2}\cdot\left(\frac{\tan(x)}{x} - \frac{1}{x^2}\right)} = \\
& e^{\frac{1}{2}\cdot\left(\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\tan(x)}{x} - \lim_{x\to0}\frac{1}{x^2}\right)} \stackrel{\frac{0}{0}}{\stackrel{=}{L}} \quad\quad \text{(LHopital only for the left lim)} \\
& e^{\frac{1}{2}\cdot\left(\lim_{x\to0}\frac{1}{\cos^2(x)} - \lim_{x\to0}\frac{1}{x^2}\right)} = \\
& e^{\frac{1}{2}\cdot\left(1 - \infty\right)} = \\
& e^{-\infty} = 0\\
\end{align}
$$

---

### Edit #1:

Continuing after the mistake of the $\tan(x)$:

$$\begin{align}
 & e^{\lim_{x\to0}\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{\sin(x)}\cdot\left(\frac{\cos(x)}{x} - \frac{\sin(x)}{x^2}\right)} = \\
& e^{\lim_{x\to0}\frac{1}{2}\cdot\left(\frac{\cot(x)}{x} - \frac{1}{x^2}\right)} = \\
& e^{\lim_{x\to0}\frac{1}{2}\cdot\left(\frac{\frac{1}{\tan(x)}}{x} - \frac{1}{x^2}\right)} = \\
& e^{\frac{1}{2}\cdot\left(\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\frac{1}{\tan(x)}}{x} - \lim_{x\to0}\frac{1}{x^2}\right)} \stackrel{\frac{0}{0}}{\stackrel{=}{L}} \quad\quad \text{(LHopital only for the left lim)} \\
& e^{\frac{1}{2}\cdot\left(\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\frac{\frac{-1}{\cos^2(x)}}{\tan^2(x)}}{1} - \lim_{x\to0}\frac{1}{x^2}\right)} = \\
& e^{\frac{1}{2}\cdot\left(\lim_{x\to0}\frac{-1}{\sin^2(x)} - \lim_{x\to0}\frac{1}{x^2}\right)} = \\
& e^{\frac{1}{2}\cdot\left(-\infty - \infty\right)} = 0\\
\end{align}
$$

Comment: $\frac{\cos x}{\sin x} = \cot x$, you wrote $\tan x$, hence got a wrong result.

Comment: @DanielFischer: I solve that problem but it still seems to be zero :/

Comment: Since $\cot$ has a pole at $0$, $\frac{\cot x}{x}$ is not not an indeterminate form if you plug in $x = 0$. It isn't one of the things you can apply L'Hospital's rule to. You can't separate the two summands, write the exponent as $\frac{x\cot x - 1}{x^2}$. But better, use the Taylor expansions rather than L'Hospital's rule, that's easier and less error-prone.

Comment: Just a suggestion on formatting: consider using $\exp(f(x))$ in place of $e^{f(x)}$. The latter can make rational exponents tough to read.

Comment: @user170231: Thx didn't thought of that! Though, BTW, it is possible to zoom in a MathJax code (at least in Firefox).

Comment: Easy trick
-------
$$\lim_{x\to 0} (\frac{\sin x}{x})^{\frac1{x^2}}  =\lim_{x\to 0}\exp\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\ln\left(\frac{\sin x -x}{x}+1\right)\right) \sim \lim_{x\to 0}\exp\left(\frac{1}{6}\frac{\ln\left(1-\frac{x^2}{6}\right)}{\frac{x^2}{6}}\right)= \exp(-\frac16)$$

Given that $$\sin x -x \sim -\frac{x^3}{6}~~~~and ~~~~ \lim_{X\to 0} \frac{\ln\left(1-X\right)}{X} = -1$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take the logarithm of your limit then use L'Hopital and Taylor series. Let the expression in the limit be $L$:

$$\begin{align}
\ln L&=\ln\left[ \left(\frac{\sin(x)}{x}\right)^{\frac{1}{x^2}} \right] \\[2ex]
 &=  \frac{\ln\left(\frac{\sin(x)}{x}\right)}{x^2} \\[2ex]
 &\to\frac{\frac{x}{\sin x}\cdot \frac{x\cos x-\sin x}{x^2}}{2x}\qquad \text{(L'Hopital)}\\[2ex]
 &=  \frac{x\cos x-\sin x}{2x^2\sin x} \\[2ex]
 &\to\frac{x(1-\frac{x^2}2)-(x-\frac{x^3}6)}{2x^2(x)}\qquad \text{(Taylor series)} \\[2ex]
 &=  \frac{-\frac 13x^3}{2x^3} \\[2ex]
 &=  -\frac 16
\end{align}$$

Therefore $L\to e^{-1/6}$. (I left a few minor gaps for you to fill in.)

If you don't like Taylor series, we can finish the whole thing with L'Hopital, though this way takes more steps.

$$\begin{align}
\ln L&\to\frac{x\cos x-\sin x}{2x^2\sin x} \qquad\text{(from above, before Taylor series)}\\[2ex]
 &\to\frac{x\cdot -\sin x +\cos x-\cos x}{2x^2\cos x + 4x\sin x} \qquad\text{(L'Hopital)}\\[2ex]
 &=  \frac{-\sin x}{2x\cos x + 4\sin x} \\[2ex]
 &\to\frac{-\cos x}{2x\cdot -\sin x+2\cos x+4\cos x}  \qquad\text{(L'Hopital)}\\[2ex]
 &=  \frac{-\cos x}{-2x\sin x+6\cos x} \\[2ex]
 &\to\frac{-1}{0+6} \\[2ex]
 &=  -\frac 16
\end{align}$$

Comment: That solution really seems good but I'm curious as to how we solve that limit without Taylor..?

Comment: @Dor: See my edited answer for a solution with Taylor series. Does this meet your needs?

Comment: Instead of doing the “hard” derivative of $\log((\sin x)/x)$, one can more simply write it as $\log|\sin x|-\log|x|$ and the derivative is $\cot x-1/x=(x\cot x-1)/x$

Comment: @RoryDaulton: Indeed thanks! :)

Comment: @egreg: You are right, but I still prefer the way I showed. Your way leads to $\cot$ and $\csc$ functions, and I avoid them whenever possible--my personal preference. And if you don't simplify the $\cot$ away, the later differentiations become more difficult.

Answer (score 3):

Using Taylor series:

$$\frac{\sin(x)}{x}=1- \frac{1}{3!}x^2+o(x^2).$$
So using this formula we get:
$$
\ln \left( \frac{\sin(x)}{x}\right)=\ln \left(1- \frac{1}{3!}x^2+o(x^2) \right).
$$
Now we can use the Taylor expansion for the $\ln$ function so we get:
$$
\ln \left(1- \frac{1}{3!}x^2+o(x^2) \right)= - \frac{1}{3!}x^2+o(x^2).
$$
Now divide all by $x^2$ and compute the limit while $x$ goes to zero:
$$
\frac{- \frac{1}{3!}x^2+o(x^2)}{x^2}
$$
as $x\rightarrow 0$, we obtain that
$$
\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \ln \left( \frac{\sin(x)}{x}\right)=
-\frac{1}{6}.
$$
At the end
$$
\lim_{x \rightarrow 0}\left(\frac{\sin(x)}{x} \right)^{\frac{1}{x^2}}=
e^{\lim_{x \rightarrow 0}\frac{\ln\frac{\sin(x)}{x}}{x^2}}=
e^{-\frac{1}{6}}.
$$

Answer (score 1):

:(  I have not enough reputation to even add a comment...

Yes, the cot<-->tan problem.

Comment: it should be equal to $e^{-\frac{1}{6}}$, if the cot<-->tan was not there.

Comment: [Wolfra Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28%28sin%28x%29%29%2Fx%29%5E%281%2Fx%5E2%29) also gets $1/(\sqrt[6]{e})$.

Comment: I solved that problem but it still seems to be 0... though Wolfram Alpha gets it otherwise. Where did I go wrong..?

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align*}
\left(\frac{\sin x}x\right)^{\frac1{x^2}}
&=\left[1+\left(\frac{\sin x}x-1\right)\right]^{\frac1{x^2}}\\
&=\left[1+\left(\frac1{x/(\sin x-x)}\right)\right]^{\frac1{x^2}}\\
&=\left[\underbrace{\left[1+\left(\frac1{x/(\sin x-x)}\right)\right]^{[x/(\sin x-x)]}}_{=:A(x)}\right]^{\frac{\sin x-x}{x^3}}
\end{align*}

Next observe that

$\bullet\sin x=x-\frac{x^3}{6}+o(x^3) \Longrightarrow\frac{\sin x-x}{x^3}\stackrel{x\to0}{\longrightarrow}-\frac16$;

$\bullet\lim_{\xi\to\infty}\left(1+\frac1\xi\right)^{\xi}=e \Longrightarrow A(x)\stackrel{x\to0}{\longrightarrow} e \;\;(\mbox{in fact} \;\;x/(\sin x-x)\stackrel{x\to0}{\longrightarrow}\infty)$

thus we immediately get
$$
\lim_{x\to0}\left(\frac{\sin x}x\right)^{\frac1{x^2}}=e^{-\frac16}
$$

Comment: That's a really nice method..!

Comment: Many thanks Dor!